# Partition Keys in List<KeyValuePair> c#

Tags: c#, keyvaluepair

I have a List of KeyValuePairs

```
var hitCoord = new List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>()
```

and sorted like this (descending by Key)

```
hitCoord.Sort((a, b) => (b.Key.CompareTo(a.Key)));
```

I can find the total highest Value with

```
hitCoord.Sort((a, b) => (b.Value.CompareTo(a.Value)));
```

(^ maybe that can be used for the following query?)

I would like to partition the Keys in my list such that I can find Values that meet a condition within the specified range of keys.

i.e. I would like to find the highest Value and Lowest Value in a range of (int)Keys

```
for (i=0; i<hitCoord.Count; i++)
{
     if (hitCoord[i].Key > (int lowerbound) && hitCoord[i].Key < (int upperBound)
     {
          find highest Value?
     }
}
```

Not sure if that is at all on the right track.  I am new to programming and very new to KeyValuePairs.  Any help you can offer on this matter is much appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Try something like this : KeyValuePair<int, double> result = hitCoord.Where(x => (x.Key > 0) && (x.Key < 100)).OrderBy(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the max value in a specified range of keys could be solved by using LINQ (`using System.Linq;`) like this:

```
hitCoord.Where(c => c.Key > lowerbound && c.Key < upperbound).Max(c => c.Value);
```

The approach:

1. Use `Where` to filter all items with key in range
2. Use `Max` to get the max value

You could adapt and extend the query also with more checks and constraints. Some basic queries are described in [Basic LINQ Query Operations (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations).

Comment: using ```System.Linq;``` is required.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to actually sort - you can do this with Linq (adding `using System.Linq;` to the top of your .cs file). You just want a `Where` to filter by key and a `Max` to get the highest value:

```
var maxValue = hitCoord.Where(hc => hc.Key > lowerbound && hc.Key < upperBound)
                       .Max(hc => hc.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested this is all pretty easy to do with linq.  here's another sample of linq calls including how to create a partition lookup.

```
var hitCoord = new List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<int, double>(1, 1.1),
    new KeyValuePair<int, double>(1, 1.2),
    new KeyValuePair<int, double>(2, 2.0),
    new KeyValuePair<int, double>(2, 2.1)
};

var partitions = hitCoord.ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key % 2);

var maxKvp = hitCoord.Max(kvp => kvp.Key);
var minKvp = hitCoord.Min(kvp => kvp.Key);

int lower = 1;
int higher = 2;

var maxInRange = hitCoord.Where(kvp => kvp.Key >= lower && kvp.Key <= higher).Max(kvp => kvp.Key);
```

That said if this is perfromance critical then you'll probably want to use something other than linq so you can optimize it and avoid going through the list multiple times.